# UWP mediaelement fullscreen window object not receiving event handlers

Tags: win-universal-app, fullscreen, mediaelement

Here is the code which I am using to simply toggle fullscreen in UWP media element:

```
private void SingleMediaElement_DoubleTapped(object sender, DoubleTappedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        SingleMediaElement.IsFullWindow = !SingleMediaElement.IsFullWindow;
    }
```

I can make it fullscreen by double clicking, but I am not able to exit fullscreen, because apparently fullscreen mode is a different object.  How do I receive that object and manage the same event handler on it?

Answer (score 2):

Try [ApplicationView](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/hh701658) instead:

```
private void SingleMediaElement_DoubleTapped(object sender, DoubleTappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
        var view = ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView();

        if (view.IsFullScreenMode)
            view.ExitFullScreenMode();
        else
            view.TryEnterFullScreenMode();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This problem was solved by using Media element Transport controls double tapped event instead of Media Element double tapped event.